# Output is Always X

Tags: system-verilog, state-machine

Whenever I write a testbench for my systemverilog code, the output seems to always be X even though the implementation is correct. Where is my error?

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module fsm( input logic clk, input logic reset, 

input logic start, clockwise,
output logic [3:0] pattern);
parameter      A=4'b1100,
               B=4'b0110,
               Ab=4'b0011,
               Bb=4'b1001;
typedef enum logic [1:0] {S0,S1,S2,S3} statetype;

statetype state, nextstate;

//state register
always@ (posedge clk)
begin
if (reset)
    state= S0;
else 
    state = nextstate;
end
//nextstate logic
always_comb
    case(state)
    S0: if(start==1 && clockwise==0)
            nextstate<= S3;
        else if(start==1&&clockwise==1)
            nextstate<=S1;
        else 
            nextstate<=S0;
    S1: if(start==1 && clockwise==0)
            nextstate<= S0;
        else if(start==1&&clockwise==1)
            nextstate<=S2;
        else 
            nextstate<=S1;
    S2: if(start==1 && clockwise==0)
            nextstate<= S1;
        else if(start==1&&clockwise==1)
             nextstate<=S3;
        else 
             nextstate<=S2;
    S3: if(start==1 && clockwise==0)
             nextstate<= S2;
        else if(start==1&&clockwise==1)
             nextstate<=S0;
        else 
             nextstate<=S3;
    endcase
//output logic
always@ (posedge clk)
    case(state)
       S0: pattern= A;
       S1: pattern= B;
       S2: pattern= Ab;
       S3: pattern= Bb;
    endcase
endmodule
```

and here is my testbench

```
module fsmtest();
logic clk, reset, clockwise, start;
logic [3:0] pattern;
fsm dut(clk, reset, start, clockwise, pattern);
//generate clock
always
    begin
        clk=0; #5; clk=1; #5;
    end
initial
    begin
        reset=0;
        start=1;
        clockwise=1;
        #10;
        start=0;
        #10;
    end
endmodule
```

I'm not sure if it is my finite state machine that is wrong or if it's the testbench. Hoping to get some help, thanks in advance.

Comment: You got your blocking/non-blocking mixed up. Combinational (`always_comb`/`always @*`) should be blocking (`=`). Sequential (`@(posedge clk)`) should be non-blocking (`<=`).

Comment: thank you I never knew about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never asserted reset, so your state machine remains uninitialized. You should fix this by adding a `default` branch to your case statement. Then, if your DUT ever comes up in an un-encoded state, it is guaranteed to get into a known state.